# Is it possible to add maxlength restriction on ComplexType?

Tags: xsd

In my XML schema I define complex type that contains a sequence of simple string elements:

```
<xs:complexType name="Nationalities">       
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Nationality">
            <xs:simpleType />
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType
```

I want whole nationalities element to have max length of 20 chars. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a restriction is not possible in XML Schema-

You can limit the length of the contents of each individual `<Nationality>` entry, and you can limit the number of subnodes below `<Nationalities>` (by specifying some max value in here `<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">` instead of the "unbounded" value) - but not the overall length of the parent node with all its subnodes and their contents - you'd have to do this on your own.